# Silverlight 4 - MVC 2 ASP.NET Membership integration "single sign on"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, asp.net-membership, azure

Scenario:

1. I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 site using ASP.NET Forms Authentication.
2. The site includes a Silverlight 4 application that needs to securely call internal web services.
3. The web services also need to be publically exposed for third party authenticated access.

Challenges:

1. Securely accessing webservices from Silverlight using the current users identity without requiring the user to re-login in in the Silverlight application.
2. Providing a secure way for third party applications to access the same webservices the same users credentials, ideally with out using ASP.NET Forms Authentication.

Additional details and limitations:

1. This application is hosted in Azure.
2. We would rather NOT use RIA Services if at all possible.

Solutions Under Consideration:

1. I think that if the webservices are part of the same MVC site that hosts the Silverlight application then forms authentication should probably "just work" from Silverlight based on the users forms auth cookies.  But this seems to rule out the possibility of hosting the webservices seperately (which is desirable in our scenario).
2. For third-party access to the web services I'm guessing that seperate endpoints with a different authenication solution is probably the right answer, but I would rather only support one version of the services if possible...

Questions:

1. Can anybody point me towards any sample applications that implements something like this?
2. How would you recommend implementing this solution?

Comment: Based on the lack of response to this question I'm going to assume there is no great answer...

Comment: SSO is a well beaten dog and there are many examples here and elsewhere but your story is arguably a corner case so there are likely not many answers from experience on tap. I will say that, from my experience, it certainly seems a reasonable and implementable story but will require some focused attention that you are not likely to get from those who have not already implemented such a story. good luck.

Comment: I have a very similar scenario. What did you actually do?

Comment: We ended up with a mixed approach:  A security webservice end point on the same site as the silverlight app to get back a security token, and then seperate webservices end points on other servers that require that token for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend WCF to use Membership as authencation store and reuse the FormsAuth Cookie (send by the MVC site) to the browser by the Silverlight app.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an STS with Windows Identity Foundation so you can have your app use claims identity and then change authentication outside the app. For third party you can use Windows Azure Access Control Service (ACS). We are updating our guidance on this and you can look at the new code to show you how to do this at our [codeplex site](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/). The original book is available at [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735640599). I would focus on the updated guide because it has ACS has websites and an active client talking to WCF. The client is WPF but it would similar for Silverlight.